# How do you emphasize unformatted Chinese text?

Tags: emphasis

In English, one can write, "I am mad at you!" as "I AM MAD AT YOU!" for greater emphasis; on the internet, it's seen as "yelling". Absent the ability to format text (say, **bold** or *italics*), what is done / can be done to emphasize a statement in Chinese other than simply adding more exclamation marks or some kind of emoticon?

Answer (score 11):

[Emphasis mark](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9D%80%E9%87%8D%E5%8F%B7) (underneath dots) is the Chinese counterpart of italics.

In printing, besides emphasis mark, fonts are used for distinguishing purposes. Bold (黑体) is also considered as a different font (rather than a variation of the same font).

In handwriting, people use straight underline and tilde underline.

[image: Example of emphasis mark]

[image: Example of bold font]

Comment: +1 I didn't know about the dots eheh :D

Comment: I have never seen the dots, actually. Perhaps it's a Mainland/Taiwan thing. Does anyone know?

Comment: @OlleLinge What I am sure is it's not a mainland-only thing as it was originated in the ancient times, see [this reference](http://www.360doc.com/content/12/0310/10/1597421_193190257.shtml) and I've seen them used in photo print of these books myself. But I don't know if in Taiwan it's not common or even obsoleted.

Comment: I saw them just yesterday in a dictionary of idioms. They were used in the pinyin character index to show the position of the character in the idiom. Copyright was 2010. I'm in South China.

Comment: @NS.X. In the ancient time, they're usually red hollow dots.

Answer (score 1):

Chinese people usually use some 语气词 like 啊, 呀 and other words describe your feeling (you can put any words here). Repeating is also a useful way (not for books). You can find that Chinese books don't ususually have such thing.

> 你笨(you are stupid)
>
> 你太笨了(you are too stupid)
>
> 你笨死了(hmmm... I don't know how to translate this well...)
>
> 完了，你笨得没救了(oh dear, nobody can't help you to be not so silly)
>
> If you've already known this person is *TOOOOO* stupid, you can even simply say 完了,你没救了.

If you understand what Chinese language really is, you may find such a thing is useless, because there are many ways to say what you *really* want to express.

In fact, "extract important points from text", "understand the writer's feeling" are a basic knowledge taught in lessons, at least middle schools.

Also the marks in the answer above are rarely used...

Comment: I would argue against the last statement. Every one of my middle school and college textbook use these marks. A lot of publications use them too. You can find them even in literature and novel books. As a matter of fact, I pick a random book from my bookshelf and I can find the emphasis mark somewhere in it.

Comment: haha, this answer is interesting!

Comment: @NS.X. I don't know what books do you have, I haven't read any books using them, to be honest.